# Automatic folder backup from XP to Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, windows-xp, directory

My HR/Finance manager stores important files & records in her Win XP desktop PC and she rarely copies all her files into our file server that runs on Windows Server 2003 (the last time she did it was 3 months ago). How do I automate folder(s) backup from her PC to the fileserver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Folder Redirection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232692), [Roaming Profiles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314478) can handle the user files properly as long as there aren't additional application-specific storage locations containing important data.

If it does warrant a 3rd party sync app, I use SyncBack Pro.
It's relatively inexpensive & verifies write operations to prevent spreading corruption, which was a difficult feature to find.

The presence of a drive with serial number foo can trigger the backup job, which helps to automate offline backup rotations to external devices similarly to what's often done with tapes.

A post-job script can be set to eject the drive and keep the data safe.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options:

The best would be to redirect her My Documents folder to a network share.

If for some reason that's not appropriate, you could use one of the many tools that syncs files between locations - rsync, Second Copy, or whatever.